# Error: Error trying to diff '[object Object]'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed

Tags: javascript, angular, rest, typescript

I'm trying to make a request to the API of Deezer and I'm having this error:

> "ERROR Error: Error trying to diff '[object Object]'. Only arrays and
>   iterables are allowed".

Could anyone guide? I am getting error, cant figure out why??

This is my **componet.ts**

`

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { TracksService } from '../services/tracks.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  // instantiate posts to an empty array
  tracks: any = [];

  constructor(private tss: TracksService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    // Retrieve posts from the API
    this.tss.getAllTracks().subscribe(data => {
      this.tracks = data;
    });
  }
}
```

`

The error must be here because I know that the problem is that probably is returning a object and not an array, but i don't see where i have the problem and don't know how.

**component.html**
`

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row" *ngFor="let track of tracks">
    <div class="card card-block">
      <h4 class="card-title">{{ track.title }}</h4>
      <img class="card-image" src="{{ track.album.cover }}" alt="image">
      <audio controls src="{{ track.preview }}"></audio>
      <p class="card-text">{{ track.duration }}</p>
      <a href="#" class="card-link">{{ track.link }}</a>
      <a href="#" class="card-link">{{ track.title }}</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

`

**track.service.ts**
`

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class TracksService {

  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  // Get all posts from the API
  getAllTracks() {
    return this.http.get('/api/radio')
      .map(res => res.json());
  }
}
```

`COMPLETE LOG`

```
HomeComponent.html:2 ERROR Error: Error trying to diff '[object Object]'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed
    at DefaultIterableDiffer.webpackJsonp.../../../core/esm5/core.js.DefaultIterableDiffer.diff (core.js:7499)
    at NgForOf.webpackJsonp.../../../common/esm5/common.js.NgForOf.ngDoCheck (common.js:2583)
    at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (core.js:12372)
    at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (core.js:13893)
    at checkAndUpdateNode (core.js:13836)
    at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (core.js:14729)
    at debugCheckDirectivesFn (core.js:14670)
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (HomeComponent.html:2)
    at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.js:14655)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:13802)
```

`

I'm a beginner so please if you see this question too obvious just ignore it, please don't put me a -1. :)

Comment: Is the error message in the console showing what line/file the error happens in?

Comment: can you post what you see when you print this.tracks =

Comment: i already added the complete log, thanks

Comment: the error means you are trying to use ngFor over an Object. check thos.tracks is an array

Comment: For some reason when i console this.tracks it says is undefined :(

Comment: @JesusSandrea , whats the output of `res.json()` ?